# Aspect printing null values for pointcut properties on AWS CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aop, amazon-cloudwatch, spring-aop

These are AWS CloudWatch logs, in which I am getting `null` value (anyways getting the package, class, method name):

```
2021-05-10 04:27:36.707  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
2021-05-10 04:27:36.707 INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
2021-05-10T09:57:36.710+05:30 Copy
2021-05-10 04:27:36.710  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.controller.PlatformController : getPlatform()arguments : [ null, null, null, null, {}, null ]
2021-05-10 04:27:36.710 INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.controller.PlatformController : getPlatform()arguments : [ null, null, null, null, { }, null ]
2021-05-10T09:57:36.711+05:30 Copy
2021-05-10 04:27:36.711  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
2021-05-10 04:27:36.711 INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
2021-05-10T09:57:36.711+05:30 Copy
2021-05-10 04:27:36.711  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
2021-05-10 04:27:36.711 INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getKeyAndSecret()arguments : [ null ]
```

Spring Boot code to generate logs (using AOP):

```java
package tech.onesilverbullet.platform.advice;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * In this class, the logic for creating the logs is written.
 */
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAdvice {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    LoggingAdvice() {
        map.put("getUserFromToken", "A AUTHENTICATION");
        map.put("doEntitlementCheck", "H ENTITLEMENT CHECK");
        map.put("getProducer", "G API SELECTION");
        map.put("callProducerApi", "M API CALL");
    }

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAdvice.class);

    /**
     * In this class, using @Pointcut which gives information where our logging
     * mechanism will be implemented. SYNTAX - @Pointcut(vale =
     * "execution(returnType
     * RootDirectoryPath.packageName.className.methodName(no.of arguments))")
     */
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* tech.onesilverbullet.platform.*.*.*(..) )")
    public void myPointcut() {

    }

    /**
     * In this method we are passing ProceedingJoinPoint which is coming from AOP.
     * 
     * @param pjp - ProceedingJoinPoint internally uses the reflection by which we
     *            can track the method called and also the details like, input
     *            parameters which are coming to that particular method.
     * @returns an object for the response in JSON.
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @Around("myPointcut()")
    public Object applicationLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String methodName = pjp.getSignature().getName();
        String className = pjp.getTarget().getClass().toString();
        Object[] array = pjp.getArgs();
        log.info("method invoked " + className + " : " + methodName + "()" + "arguments : "
                + mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(array));
        Object object = pjp.proceed();
        String getStepId = map.get(methodName);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info(className + " : " + methodName + "()" + "response : " + object + "StepId : " + getStepId
                + " Execution Time : " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
        return object;
    }

}
```

Logs I am getting locally. I see everything locally, but not on AWS CloudWatch:

```
getKeyAndSecret()response : [Ljava.lang.String;@6fd2fb0StepId : null Execution Time : 2 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:01.926  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getUserFromToken()arguments : [ "abcduoieau", "kuhoahiwad" ] -- this method is also not showing on AWS but showing locally
2021-05-07 16:43:01.926  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getUserByToken()arguments : [ "abcduoieau", "kuhoahiwad" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:02.574  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getUserByToken()response : Consumer(apiKey=abcduoieau, apiSecret=kuhoahiwad, consumerId=kedar1023)StepId : null Execution Time : 648 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.574  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getUserFromToken()response : Consumer(apiKey=abcduoieau, apiSecret=kuhoahiwad, consumerId=kedar1023)StepId : A AUTHENTICATION Execution Time : 648 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.575  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : doEntitlementCheck()arguments : [ "kedar1023", "insurance", "literm", "v1", "customer" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:02.577  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getUserDetails()arguments : [ "kedar1023", "literm" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:02.640  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getUserDetails()response : ConsumerEntitlement(consumerId=kedar1023, category=insurance, apiId=literm, versionId=v1)StepId : null Execution Time : 64 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.640  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : doEntitlementCheck()response : ConsumerEntitlement(consumerId=kedar1023, category=insurance, apiId=literm, versionId=v1)StepId : H ENTITLEMENT CHECK Execution Time : 66 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.641  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getProducer()arguments : [ "literm", "v1" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:02.642  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getProducerDetails()arguments : [ "literm", "v1" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:02.740  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.repository.PlatformRepository : getProducerDetails()response : Provider(apiId=literm, typeOfRequest=GET, apiVersion=v1, typeOfApi=REST, url=https://jni1ik9z9d.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/insurance/literm/v1/getquotes)StepId : null Execution Time : 99 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.740  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.PlatformService : getProducer()response : Provider(apiId=literm, typeOfRequest=GET, apiVersion=v1, typeOfApi=REST, url=https://jni1ik9z9d.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/insurance/literm/v1/getquotes)StepId : G API SELECTION Execution Time : 100 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:02.741  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : method invoked class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.RestService : callProducerApi()arguments : [ "https://jni1ik9z9d.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev/insurance/literm/v1/getquotes" ]
2021-05-07 16:43:03.762  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.service.RestService : callProducerApi()response : {"name": "Divyanka Kumari", "birthday": "8-2-1991", "gender": "female", "employed": "true", "address": "Uttrakhand", "maritalStatus": "single", "phone no.": "9096426545"}StepId : M API CALL Execution Time : 1021 ms
2021-05-07 16:43:03.763  INFO 17856 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] t.o.platform.advice.LoggingAdvice        : class tech.onesilverbullet.platform.controller.PlatformController : getPlatform()response : {"name": "Divyanka Kumari", "birthday": "8-2-1991", "gender": "female", "employed": "true", "address": "Uttrakhand", "maritalStatus": "single", "phone no.": "9096426545"}StepId : null Execution Time : 1870 ms
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give your questions a bit more love and make them readable in the future. I added proper code formatting, syntax highlighting, fixed the worst spelling errors and removed the escape sequences from your logs.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there is no problem with the aspect, but the kind of information you are trying to log is stripped from the logs on the production or pre-production server with real customer data. This kind of thing is a hard requirement in many regulated industries, such as banking. Look at what you are trying to access:

- `getKeyAndSecret()`: sounds like trying to access highly confidential information
- `getPlatform()`: prints personal user data in your second log

I might be wrong, of course, because you just show an aspect here, no application code. Another possibility is that in `mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(array)` there is a bug somewhere.